# How to backup a specific Monngodb database with date condition

Tags: mongodb

Monngod db

We are creating database daily based on date  like `ERROR_LOG_12012016`.

We now back up on a daily basis when I take dump its done all attached database for here we need to yesterday database only how to do that kindly help this

Regards,
Baskar r

Answer (score 0):

I Think you are looking for this

```
mongodump --collection myCollection --db test
```

Based on your comment you should run the cron every day.
Try executing the command in shell script.[MongoDump with timestamp](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/mongodb-user/119vcry6kt/mongodump-with-timestamp)

Comment: thanks for your input sir ...  i need automatically  not manually  and moreover database like daily ERROR_LOG_12012016,ERROR_LOG_13012016 creating like

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mongoexport](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-import-and-export-example/)

```
mongoexport -d database_name -c collection_name -o output_file.json
```

To make it run automatically, follow the below steps

**step1:** write shell script, Your shell script will be as below,

```
#!/bin/bash
# My first script
mongoexport -d database_name -c collection_name -o output_file.json
```

**step2:** Save the file by name **filename**

**step3:** Try running file by command **./filename**

**step4:** Add this command to [crontab](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/cron-every-5-minutes/)